# LinearLayout with multiline and singleline

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:cacheColorHint="#0000" 
        android:background="@layout/selectorgreybutton"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            style="@style/wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/group_type"  
                android:paddingRight="10dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17dip" 
                android:singleLine="false"
                />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/group_num" 
                android:paddingRight="10dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17dip"            
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/group_type"           
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:text="&gt;"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        style="@style/wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that I only can display completly the 1st `TextView` but not the 2nd inside the `LinearLayout`, this one appears with dots... And I want to display always the 2nd `TextView` completely, and the 1st one autoadjust in 1 or 2 lines. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
       android:maxWidth="100dip"
      android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

this attribute for 1st textview and remaining width will use second textview.

Comment: This layout belongs to a row in a listview, so if I use this, I cant do click on the row

Comment: For doing click---> You might have written your own adapter. In that you can write onClickLister for each textview.

Comment: or refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451947/onlistitemclick-not-working-for-listview-in-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692303/android-listview-item-not-selectable

Comment: but then if the user doesnt click on the textview the box wont be pressed.I want the user be able to click elsewhere

Comment: you can use the click in the hole layout. but you need to give a name to your linearlayout.

Answer (score 0):

On the second textview use these  `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: @Dayerman let me see you want tow textview but on multiline and other not. So if the second one is to big a first will disapear ? i'm confused.